# What is the warning icon the project in Eclipse and how to create it?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want create Project with icon warning like this but I try create Project but it always create Project without icon warning

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an icon 'decorator'. These are added by the view using the Eclipse decoration manager.

That specific decorator is added when there are warning markers on resources in the project.

Markers are created by plug-ins using the `createMarker` method of `IResource` (usually its derived interfaces `IFile`, `IFolder` or `IProject`).